# When request forward to diferent endpoint from zuul, some of the post parameter get droped

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix

In spring boot + entflix zuul, when I redirect from route filter in zuul to different endpoint than the original, the post param which is empty get dropped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Its strange, still coulndt figure out the exactly reason for that. As usually HttpServelteRequest POST request goes as same what was in original. But in zuul, the request object are get wrapped with zuul neflix request, perhaps can be happened. May be netflix guys can answer for this.

Recently I was able to find a workaround for this to get request and response facade for netflix context object and then redirect. It worked for me.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
import com.netflix.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

/**
 * 
 * @author Sivakumaran Kathamutthu
 *
 */
@Component
public class RouteFilter extends ZuulFilter {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RouteFilter.class);


  @Override
  public String filterType() {
    return "route";
  }

  @Override
  public int filterOrder() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return redirectFrom != null && !redirectFrom.trim().isEmpty()
        && RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest().getRequestURI().contains(redirectFrom);
  }

  @Override
  public Object run() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    setRouteHost(context);

    return null;
  }

  /**
   * This method allows to set the route host into the Zuul request context
   * provided as parameter. The url is extracted from the orginal request and
   * the host is extracted from it.
   *
   * @param context the provided Zuul request context
   */
  private void setRouteHost(RequestContext context) {

    String requestURI = context.getRequest().getRequestURI();

    try {

      Field requestField = ReflectionUtils.findField(HttpServletRequestWrapper.class, "req", HttpServletRequest.class);

      if (requestField != null) {

        requestField.setAccessible(true);

        // Get the com.netflix.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper
        HttpServletRequestWrapper zuulWrappedRequest = (HttpServletRequestWrapper) ReflectionUtils.getField(requestField, ((HttpServletRequestWrapper) context.getRequest()).getRequest());

        // Get the requestFacade where original request resides
        RequestFacade requestFacade = (RequestFacade) ReflectionUtils.getField(requestField, zuulWrappedRequest);

        // Get the responseFacade where original response resides
        ResponseFacade responseFacade = (ResponseFacade) ((HttpServletResponseWrapper) context.getResponse()).getResponse();



        requestFacade.getRequestDispatcher("home/home.jsp").forward(requestFacade, responseFacade);

      } else {

        throw new RuntimeException("req field is not availble in HTTPServletRequest");
      }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

      throw e;    
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Thanks for the solution